# Проверка атрибута

Tags: python, flask

Как для view-функции gen_password добавить проверку что length числовой параметр, неотрицательный, входит в диапазон от 8 до 24.

```
@app.route('/gen-password')
def gen_password():
    def_length = 10
    length = int(request.args.get('length', def_length))

    return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(length)])
```

Answer (score 1):

`if type(length) == int and 8 <= length <= 24`

Исправление:

```
try:
    length = int(request.args.get('length', def_length))
except ValueError:
    return 'Не число'
else:
    if 8 <= length <= 24 :
        return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(length)])
```

Comment: @insolor от этого программа вылетать не начнет, так я считаю, что ответ рабочий. Просто первое условие можно убрать.

Comment: @insolor Понял. Исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в `request.args.get` передать требуемый тип значения (в данном случае `int`):

```
length = request.args.get('length', def_length, int)
```

Тогда при получении неправильного типа значения (например, строки вместо числа)  будет браться значение по-умолчанию из второго параметра. Приведение результата к целому числу в этом случае не нужно.

После этого уже можно просто проверить значение на попадание в нужный диапазон:

```
@app.route('/gen-password')
def gen_password():
    def_length = 10
    length = request.args.get('length', def_length, int)

    if not (8 <= length <= 24):
        # Если не попадает в нужный диапазон, установить значение по-умолчанию
        length = def_length

    return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(length)])
```

Если нужно выводить ошибку, если значение неправильного типа, то нужно попытку приведения к `int` обернуть в блок `try-except` и отлавливать исключение `ValueError`:

```
@app.route('/gen-password')
def gen_password():
    def_length = 10

    length = request.args.get('length', def_length)
    try:
        length = int(length)
    except ValueError:
        abort(400, f"Неправильное значение параметра length: {length}")

    if not (8 <= length <= 24):
        abort(400, f"Неправильное значение параметра length: {length}")

    return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(length)])
```

В данном случае при неправильном значении будет открываться страница "400 Bad Request" с текстом ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться встроенной функцией `type`:

```
type(length) == int and 8 <= length and length <= 24
```

Comment: Ответ нерабочий: если посмотреть на код во вопросе, то видно потому что length получено в результате приведения к целому числу. В любом случае будет или int, или исключение при попытке приведения к целому числу до этой проверки.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, сделал немного по ругому

```
@app.route('/gen-password')
def gen_password():
    def_length = 10
    if 'length' not in request.args:
        return make_response(("length", 400))
    length = int(request.arg.get['length'])
    digits = int(request.arg.get('digits', 0))
    specials = int(request.arg.get('special', 0))
    generation_symbols = string.ascii_lowercase
    if digits == 1:
        generation_symbols += string.digits
    if specials == 1:
        generation_symbols += '!@#$!%^&*()'
    """ /gen-password?length=5 Передаем значение от клиента """
    # length = int(request.args.get('length', def_length)
    """ Возвращаем строку как результат генерации списка """
    return ''.join([random.choice(generation_symbols) for _ in range(length)])
```

Comment: В итоге сделали без проверки типа данных вообще, и при передаче строк будет падать с ошибкой HTTP 500